# Rewind animations in Flash CS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have made an animation in Flash CS3 and i need to reverse this in the timeline.
I tried this, but it did not work:

```
if(!this.flag)
{
    this.flag=1;
    this.stop();
    this.fwd_btn.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler.bind(this));

    function fl_MouseClickHandler() {
        this.on("tick", ffwd.bind(this));
    }

    this.rew_btn.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_2.bind(this));

    function fl_MouseClickHandler_2() {
        this.on("tick", rewind.bind(this));
    }

    function ffwd(e) {
        this.gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame + 1);
    }

    function rewind(e) {
        this.gotoAndStop((this.currentFrame + this.getDuration() - 1) % this.getDuration());
    }
}
```

How can i do this by using Action Script code or by using the timeline functions?

Answer (score 1):

You should try Greensock TweenMax with frame plugin, it allows you to go to a particular frame (even in reverse) very simply. You can also target a label.

```
TweenMax.to(this, 2,  {frame:1}); 
//In 2 seconds, stage timeline will go to first frame.
```

Have a look here : http://www.snorkl.tv/2010/10/overview-of-tweenmax-framelabel-and-frame-plugins-nifty-way-to-play-a-flash-timeline-backwards/